# The VBA Macro function cannot return the string in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-apps-script, range

I am kinda ok with the VBA but I have very less clue about the Apps Script as it uses a different coding language.

Is there a way to transform this code for the Apps Script? Here are the details of my code in VBA and what I tried in the Apps Script:

```
Function matchstring(input1) as String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    row2 = ws.Range("E1").Row
    col2 = ws.Range("E1").Column
    c = False
    row3 = row2
    row1 = input1.Row
    col1 = input1.Column
    
    While c = False And row3 < lastrow

        'Check A'

        a = input1.Value
        b = ws.Cells(row3, col2).Value
        d = ws.Cells(row3, col2 - 3).Value
        e = Cells(row1, col1 - 3).Value
        i = 1
        
        'Check B'
        
        f = ws.Cells(row3, col2).Value
        g = ws.Cells(row3, col2 - 1).Value
        h = "Spain"
        
        'Check C'
        
        i = ws.Cells(row3, col2).Value
        j = ws.Cells(row3, col2 - 2).Value
        k = Cells(row1, col1 - 2).Value
        
        If InStr(1, a, b, 1) And e = d And j = k And g = h Then
            c = True
            matchstring = b
        Else
            row3 = row3 + 1
            c = False
        End If
    Wend
End Function
```

However, when I tried to implement this code below in the App Script, the code always returns errors:

```
function matchstring(input1) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var lastrow = ws.getRange("B" + ws.getLastRow()).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow() + 1;
  var row2 = ws.getRange("E1").getRow();
  var col2 = ws.getRange("E1").getColumn();  
  var c = false;
  var row3 = row2;
  var row1 = input1.getRow;
  var col1 = input1.getColumn;
  while (!c && row3 < lastrow) {
    // Check A
    var a = input1.getA1Notation;
    var b = ws.getRange(row3, col2).getA1Notation();
    var d = ws.getRange(row3, col2 - 3).getA1Notation();
    var e = ws.getRange(row1, col1 - 3).getA1Notation();

    // Check B
    var g = ws.getRange(row3, col2 - 1).getA1Notation();
    var h = "Spain";
  
    // Check C
    var j = ws.getRange(row3, col2 - 2).getA1Notation();
    var k = ws.getRange(row1, col1 - 2).getA1Notation();
  
    if (a.indexOf(b) !== -1 && e === d && j === k && g === h) {
      c = true;
      return b;
    } else {
      row3++;
      c = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The first error I received is related to the input1 (input1.getRow is not a function) because I think it is not yet defined in the Apps Script, but works in the GSheet.

Then I received a second error:
Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange. (line 15).

This code could be totally wrong because I have very less knowledge on how Apps Script works.

Thank you in advance and I am always open to give further details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you almost got it! as a rule of thumb the error "is not a function" usually means "add () at the end of the word" so I believe the whole problem should be solved by changing this:

```js
 var row1 = input1.getRow;
 var col1 = input1.getColumn;
```

to this:

```js
 var row1 = input1.getRow();
 var col1 = input1.getColumn();
```

I believe this should also fix your other error as the parameter marked as "null" means that the code was unable to retrieve data for the variable in place, since the variable trying to be called is row1 then I believe making this change should fix the whole thing, could you test and let me know if it worked?